# jQuery display datatime readable for the users

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I am trying to get my data saved in MongoDb to the user using loading data via AJAX and the format of the datetime in MongoDB is in this format

**2017-03-16T14:11:48.700000**

How i can display the datetime readable for the user or to display it localized by user location:

**1. Option -> 2017-03-16 14:11:48**

**2. Option -> Mar 16, 2017, 14:11:48 PM**

I would to get the **second option using javascript**.

Thanks

Comment: *I would to get the second option using javascript.* And i would get a cup of coffe and a croissant please. *Sarkasm off* What have you tried yet? wich problem are you facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I will use some libs such as momentjs or xdate to solve this(https://momentjs.com/, http://arshaw.com/xdate/)

In other way, you can use native JS to deal with:

```
var date = new Date('2017-03-16T14:11:48.700000')
date.getMonth()+1  // 3
date.getDate() // 16
date.getFullYear() // 2017
...
```

Comment: Without using lib, I think you have to implement your function to format your date, and concat string.

Comment: This is some discussion for related issues, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript